# Weak law of large numbers proof?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

The Chebyshev's inequality is given by
$$
P(|X-\mu|\geq a) \leq \frac{\sigma^2}{a^2}
$$
and the proof of the weak law of large numbers (which expresses the "convergence in probability") is given by
[image]
but how is $\geq$ changed to $>$ and where does the $n$ come from in the denominator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, we have the inequalities
$$
\mathbb P(|X-\mu|>a)\leq \mathbb P(|X-\mu|\geq a)\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{a^2}
$$
since the event $\{|X-\mu|>a\}$ is contained in the event $\{|X-\mu|\geq a\}$.

The $n$ in the denominator comes from comparing the standard deviation of $\bar X_n$ to the standard deviation of $X_n$, since $\sigma^2(\bar X_n)=\tfrac1{n}\sigma^2(X_n)$ follows from the variances calculation
$$
\textrm{Var}(\bar X_n)=\textrm{Var}\bigl(\tfrac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\bigr)=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\textrm{Var}(X_i)=\frac{1}{n}\textrm{Var}(X_n),
$$
assuming that $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d.

Comment: oh, thanks! But I still do not see *why* $\geq$ is changed to $>$ - you made me understand why it is possible (maybe I should have worded my question better and not used "how"). Like if $\mathbb P(|X-\mu|>a)\leq \mathbb P(|X-\mu|\geq a)\leq \frac{\sigma^2}{a^2}$, why not just use $\mathbb P(|X-\mu|\geq a)$ when proving?

Comment: To answer the "why" question requires some mind reading... but here's what I can come up with. Since $\epsilon$ will be sent to $0$ at the end of the proof, it turns out not to matter whether one uses $\geq \epsilon$ or $>\epsilon$ in the event. Given that it does not matter, maybe the author thought it looked stylistically cleaner to write $>\epsilon$ instead of $\geq \epsilon$? By the way, I don't see any compelling mathematical reason to change the event from $\geq \epsilon$ to $>\epsilon$ (it could even just be carelessness) but it is not wrong.